# How to maintain the hover state while hovering the submenu?

Tags: hover

im trying to make the button in hover state while the cursor still in the submenu but can't figure out. Really need help! Thanks!

```
function hideAllCat() {
    $("#categories").hide();
}

hideAllCat();

$("#tab50").mouseover(function(){            
    hideAllCat();
    $("#categories").slideDown();
});

$("#categories").mouseleave(function() {
    hideAllCat();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5RtR/24/

Answer (score 0):

Your `#tab50` element are not the parent to #categories element, therefore you cannot use the pseudo-class `:hover`. `:hover` only works when the object is right under you mouse arrow. That being said, you now have 2 (++) possible solutions.

1. Make `#tab50` parent to `#categories`. The when the sub-menu expands, the #tab50 also expands correspondingly.
2. Use javascript to do the job. `$("#categories").mouseover(function({$("#tab50").css({'background':'#abc','color':'red'})});`
   And remember to change the colors of `#tab50` back to normal in `$("#categories").mouseleave();`

**Note:**

- `#categories` should be a `class` instead of an `id`, since `hideAllCat()` should hide all `categories`, and one cannot have more than 1 `id` in a html file.

Comment: thats the only option i have since im working based on an online template which i don't have access on the html and only javascript and css basically. 
current this works for me: 


`$("#categories2 ").mouseenter(function(){
  $("#tab52 a").addClass("tabhover");
 });
$("#categories2 ").on('mouseleave', function() {
   $("#tab52 a").removeClass(tabhover');
 });`

I'm not sure if this is correct since i have more tabs

Comment: So you are saying it is working? But you don't know if it is correct? Can you please clarify it, or state it in another way? 

By the look of your code lines, they will work.

`.removeClass(tabhover')` **A missing quotation mark** btw